# Cell location co-ordinates

Tags: dna, human-anatomy, human-genome

I have just had the nails on both my big toes removed.  I am much happier.  But it got me to thinking, as there is no 'root structure' from which the nail grows, is there an x,y,z, type co-ordinate system in the genome which says the nail cell structure starts from here or what is the determining factor which says these skin related cells stop forming here and now nail cells start forming but only in this narrow band.

Comment: Why do you say there's no 'root structure' from which the nail grows? Have you read anything about the anatomy of nail growth which leads you to believe there's no root structure?